# Nested jQuery calls: how do I find out what's going on?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on some legacy jQuery code, and there's a part that is more or less like this:

```
tjq("table#tabla_pedidos tr td").click(function(){
    .
    .
    .
    tjq("body").on('click',".popup-delete", function(){
        var title = "Confirm";
        var question = "Are you sure?";
        var cancel = "NO";
        var accept = "YES";
        tjq.when( dialog(title, question, cancel, accept) ).then(
```

Where "tjq" is the name given to "$" in this code, in order to avoid conflicts.

What does the code do? Given an HTML table, when the user clicks on it it displays a popup, and if the user clicks on a button (`".popup-delete"`) in it, it displays another confirmation popup.

My problems is that this second confirmation popup doesn't work. The error I get is:

```
dialog.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
at dialog (dialog.js:5)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (VM337 scripts.js:388)
at HTMLBodyElement.dispatch (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4)
at HTMLBodyElement.r.handle (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4)
```

I have tried adding `tjq.dialog(` instead. but then the error I get is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: tjq.dialog is not a function
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (VM375 scripts.js:388)
at HTMLBodyElement.dispatch (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4)
at HTMLBodyElement.r.handle (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4)
```

I *think* it must have something to do with the nested jQuery calls, but there are others in the code that seem to work (at least with the "tjq." prefix). How can I even start to debug this? What's going on?

EDIT: to answer the questions asked below. First of all, I had thought that "dialog()" was the "dialog" widget that comes with jQuery. It turns out that this wasn't the case. Here is dialog.js:

```
function dialog(title, question, cancel, accept){

    var answer = new jQuery.Deferred();

    $("body").append("<div id='dialog'><div class='dialog-bg'></div><div class='dialog-window'><p class='dialog-title'>"+ title +"</p><p class='dialog-question'>"+ question +"</p><div class='dialog-actions'><button class='dialog-cancel'>"+ cancel +"</button><button class='dialog-accept'>"+ accept +"</button></div></div></div>");

    $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");

    $("body").on('click', '.dialog-cancel', function(){
        $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
        $("#dialog").remove();
        answer.resolve (false);
    });

    $("body").on('click', '.dialog-accept', function(){
        $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
        $("#dialog").remove();
        answer.resolve (true);
    });

    return answer.promise();
};
```

As for "tjq", it's called before the code I've excerpted, in this line:

```
tjq = jQuery.noConflict();
```

The way the page is loaded is:

1. jQuery 1.11.3.
2. jQuery-migrate 1.2.1.
3. The "tjq" thing mentioned above.
4. jQuery UI.

Comment: could you post the dialog function's code ?

Comment: How are you overriding `$` with `tjq`? Is this a config file, are you wrapping it in an IIFE?

Comment: Does your code call [`jQuery.noconflict()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) somewhere? If not, the `$` is still being mapped to jQuery. And, why not just call jQuery with `jQuery....` after doing that instead of creating a custom reference?

Comment: Show us `dialog.js`. It seems you forgot to pass jQuery there

Comment: Sorry for the delay, guys. I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Okay, as mentioned by Anton above, it turns out that I had mapped jQuery to "tlq" instead of the default "$", but hadn't modified dialog.js to account for that. Why hadn't I notice it? Because I thought that "dialog()" was the default jQuery dialog widget, and not our own function.

Furthermore, "dialog.js" is used in another part of our website where jQuery isn't mapped, and it works fine there. Looks like someone just copied and pasted the code and didn't bother checking anything else.

I don't know whether to let this question stand or just delete it; I doubt that other users will find any useful answers here...